# How do I see the most recent Open Street Maps in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm using mapbox-gl-js to overlay a campus map for a university. The buildings shown in Mapbox look like this:
[image]

But if I look on Open Street Map's site (openstreetmap.org), that version has much better buildings (that more closely reflect reality and therefore fit nicely with my campus map that I want to overlay).

[image]

I thought that Mapbox used OSM, so why doesn't it show the same buildings? Is the Mapbox data old, it says the Streets maps are updated as frequently as every five minutes? Is it the Mapbox style showing something different to the buildings I see in OSM?

The most important question for me is, if I edit OSM (to fix up this campus), will the change be visible in my Mapbox maps?

For reference, the location: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/-33.88341/151.20063

Comment: Even if the vector data is the same - it all depends very much on the styles. For example: https://openmaptiles.github.io/osm-liberty-gl-style/#18.12/-33.88343/151.20081/49.6

Comment: OpenMapTiles vector data is not "the same" as Mapbox Streets vector data. They're completely different data processing pipelines run on separate infrastructure, even if the ultimate source of both is OSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapBox stopped importing OSM data for now, either partly or completely. The details are not publicly known. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257411/23837 and https://twitter.com/Anonymaps/status/913812009547902978.

If you need to show more recent OSM data then switch to a different OSM tile provider. [switch2osm.org](https://switch2osm.org/providers/) has a list of commercial OSM tile providers. Alternatively you can [render tiles yourself](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

Comment: That's crazy! I'll see if this gets a response https://twitter.com/D__Gilbertson/status/979084050378850304

Answer (score 3):

Mapbox's "Mapbox Streets" layer is derived from OpenStreetMap, with substantial processing. There is not, afaik, any public indication of exactly how often the data processing jobs are run. But from memory:

- different layers are processed on different timelines (roads are updated more frequently than land boundaries, for instance)
- some of the layers are only processed every few months

Changes that you make in OSM will *eventually* be visible in Mapbox.

It's also possible that what you're seeing is not out of date OSM data, but a result of the processing of OSM data into vector tiles, which can result in simplification.

You might find this blog post I wrote helpful: "[OpenStreetMap vector tiles: mixing and matching engines, schemas and styles](https://stevebennett.me/2017/08/23/openstreetmap-vector-tiles-mixing-and-matching-engines-schemas-and-styles/)"

Comment: OK I've looked at a few buildings that are there in OSM but not in Mapbox and the oldest is 'last edited' 5 months ago, so I guess I'll just wait. Thanks.